# how to get Image from Clipboard using win32Api on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, clipboard

I'm using Win32Api pkg, and I was able to save the image to clipboard but i don't know how to retrieve it.

```
void getScreenShot() async {
int x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h;
//! get screen dimensions
x1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
y1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
x2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
y2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
w = x2 - x1;
h = y2 - y1;

//! copy screen to bitmap
int hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
int hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
int hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, w, h);
int oldObj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hScreen, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);

//! save bitmap to clipboard
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
CloseClipboard();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you could try to call [OpenClipboard function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to open the clipboard for examination and prevent other applications from modifying the clipboard content.

And then call [GetClipboardData function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with a type of `CF_BITMAP` to get the handle to the image data stored on the clipboard.

Comment: @Anas-Qasem Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.